# what's the range of contentOffset

Tags: uiscrollview, uinavigationbar

When using setContentOffset, what's the range of contentOffset?

Normally it seems that there's no constraint, but I also found that when the scrollView is in a viewController which is embed in navigationController and **the navigationBar is shown**, the contentOffset must be smaller than contentSize.(eh,I actually means `contentOffset.x < contentSize.width - scrollView.bounds.size.width` and `contentOffset.height < contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height`). If the contentOffset.x or contentOffset.y is out of that range, then that value is the max value, i.e `contentSize.width - scrollView.bounds.size.width`.

But when **setting the navigationBar hidden**, the contentOffset has no constraint, I can set any value and the offset works as wanted.

So did I miss something? why the hidden of navigationBar has effects on scrollView's contentOffset?

I also create a project to illustrate this problem on [github](https://github.com/comcuter/ScrollViewContentOffset).

Comment: Maybe what you need is `.contentInset`. Go and checkout the Creating and Configuring Scroll Views section in the UIScrollView Programming Guide for iOS.

Comment: @ZhangChn Pretty good alternative, but I'm just curious about the strange behavior of UIScrollView's `contentOffset` property.